# const pointer on Poco::AutoPtr

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

Try work const pointers with AutoPtr:

```
void LiveTimeConfig::setup(const AbstractConfiguration& cfg){
    GetLogger().information("LiveTimeConfig::setup(): init data");
    Poco::AutoPtr<const AbstractConfiguration> view = 
    cfg.createView("live_time");
    try {
       readExist(view, Field::Token, _token);
       readExist(view, Field::Solt, _solt);
    } catch (Poco::SyntaxException& ) {
         GetLogger().error("LiveTimeConfig::setup(): bad values");
         throw Poco::RuntimeException("LiveTimeConfig::setup(): invalid format");
    }
}
```

But I have error on comparison operator.

```
../../../build/pc/include/Poco/AutoPtr.h: In instantiation of ‘class Poco::AutoPtr<const Poco::Util::AbstractConfiguration>’: src/LiveTimeConfig.cpp:27:54:   required from here ../../../../build/pc/include/Poco/AutoPtr.h:263:7: error: ‘bool Poco::AutoPtr<C>::operator==(C*) const [with C = const Poco::Util::AbstractConfiguration]’ cannot be overloaded   bool operator == (C* ptr) const
       ^ ../../../../build/pc/include/Poco/AutoPtr.h:258:7: error: with ‘bool Poco::AutoPtr<C>::operator==(const C*) const [with C = const Poco::Util::AbstractConfiguration]’   bool operator == (const C* ptr) const
       ^ ../../../../build/pc/include/Poco/AutoPtr.h:278:7: error: ‘bool Poco::AutoPtr<C>::operator!=(C*) const [with C = const Poco::Util::AbstractConfiguration]’ cannot be overloaded   bool operator != (C* ptr) const
       ^ ../../../../build/pc/include/Poco/AutoPtr.h:273:7: error: with ‘bool Poco::AutoPtr<C>::operator!=(const C*) const [with C = const Poco::Util::AbstractConfiguration]’   bool operator != (const C* ptr) const
       ^ ../../../../build/pc/include/Poco/AutoPtr.h:293:7: error: ‘bool Poco::AutoPtr<C>::operator<(C*) const [with C = const Poco::Util::AbstractConfiguration]’ cannot be overloaded   bool operator < (C* ptr) const
       ^ ../../../../build/pc/include/Poco/AutoPtr.h:288:7: error: with ‘bool Poco::AutoPtr<C>::operator<(const C*) const [with C = const Poco::Util::AbstractConfiguration]’   bool operator < (const C* ptr) const
       ^ ../../../../build/pc/include/Poco/AutoPtr.h:308:7: error: ‘bool Poco::AutoPtr<C>::operator<=(C*) const [with C = const Poco::Util::AbstractConfiguration]’ cannot be overloaded   bool operator <= (C* ptr) const
       ^ ../../../../build/pc/include/Poco/AutoPtr.h:303:7: error: with ‘bool Poco::AutoPtr<C>::operator<=(const C*) const [with C = const Poco::Util::AbstractConfiguration]’   bool operator <= (const C* ptr) const
       ^ ../../../../build/pc/include/Poco/AutoPtr.h:323:7: error: ‘bool Poco::AutoPtr<C>::operator>(C*) const [with C = const Poco::Util::AbstractConfiguration]’ cannot be overloaded   bool operator > (C* ptr) const
       ^ ../../../../build/pc/include/Poco/AutoPtr.h:318:7: error: with ‘bool Poco::AutoPtr<C>::operator>(const C*) const [with C = const Poco::Util::AbstractConfiguration]’   bool operator > (const C* ptr) const
       ^ ../../../../build/pc/include/Poco/AutoPtr.h:338:7: error: ‘bool Poco::AutoPtr<C>::operator>=(C*) const [with C = const Poco::Util::AbstractConfiguration]’ cannot be overloaded   bool operator >= (C* ptr) const
       ^ ../../../../build/pc/include/Poco/AutoPtr.h:333:7: error: with ‘bool Poco::AutoPtr<C>::operator>=(const C*) const [with C = const Poco::Util::AbstractConfiguration]’   bool operator >= (const C* ptr) const
```

How create AutoPtr for *const AbstractConfiguration**

**UPD**

if using

```
const Poco::AutoPtr<AbstractConfiguration> view = cfg.createView("live_time");
```

Error is

```
/home/evgen/projects/AuthService/Core/Module/src/LiveTimeConfig.cpp:27: error: invalid conversion from ‘const Poco::Util::AbstractConfiguration*’ to ‘Poco::Util::AbstractConfiguration*’ [-fpermissive]
 const Poco::AutoPtr<AbstractConfiguration> view = cfg.createView("live_time");
                                                                             ^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only using *const_cast* success build and work, but I think is it hack and smell code.

```
const Poco::AutoPtr<AbstractConfiguration> view = const_cast<AbstractConfiguration*>(cfg.createView("live_time"));
```

Comment: I'm afraid you cannot avoid it with this design of AutoPtr. Things you can do is report this SO question to producer of AutoPtr and create wrapper over const_cast (so you can easly remove it when fixed) with something like std::make_unique. I can do some example in few hours if needed

Answer (score 1):

I don't know this library nor its internals, but seems it has problems with operating on const-types internally. That shouldn't be a problem though, since, as comes from [header](https://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.AutoPtr.html), `get` function has two overloads and the one for `const` object instance returns `const` pointer. (`const C * get() const;`) So you could use:

```
const Poco::AutoPtr<AbstractConfiguration> view = 
cfg.createView("live_time");
```

as pointer to `const AbstractConfiguration`.

EDIT:

Reason of this compiler error can be read from this header as well.
So, AutoPtr class declares pair of functions for each operator `==`, etc. ...

```
bool operator == (
    const C * ptr
) const;
```

and

```
bool operator == (
    C * ptr
) const;
```

But when you declare  `Poco::AutoPtr<const AbstractConfiguration>` both overloads have same declaration

```
bool operator == (
    const AbstractConfiguration * ptr
) const;
```

which invokes a compilation error.

[Minimal example](https://ideone.com/jNu9wT)

Comment: Thanks for detailed reply. Apparently creation Poco::AutoPtr for pointer on const object is not possible. P.S. const Poco::AutoPtr<AbstractConfiguration> is not work.

Comment: What do you mean by "`const Poco::AutoPtr<AbstractConfiguration>` is not work"? It does not compile? What is an error then?

Comment: @KopysovEvgeniy Comment above, forgot to call

Answer (score 1):

Poco::AutoPtr assumes reference-counting i.e. modifying of the counter within object. This conflicts with object's const